# Apex "Edit" and Create button on the Report and Form pages. Is there any ways to lead to different pages?

Tags: apex

I started to learn Apex recently.

I made a report and Form page on Apex.

when I click "Edit" and "Create Button", it goes to the same page.

Is there any ways

For example,

If I click "Edit" on  Report page, It leads to page 4
If I click "Create button" on report page, it leads to page 5

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Not sure if this is what you're after, but it sounds like you need to adjust where the link redirects.

If you run your app, then click 'show edit links' or something similar on the bottom of the screen to the right, you will see the orange button next to page items. Click it and edit the object in the following popup.

Hope this helps!